# Sorting a ListBox of objects by attributes

Tags: c#, sorting, object, listbox

I have a list created by:

```
List<Song> SongList = new List<Song>();
```

Populated by a bunch of:

```
SongList.Add(new Song(songID, "Dirt", "Alice in Chains", "Rooster", "Rock", "02:32"));
```

The details of songs are populated into a ListBox by:

```
private void songTitle_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = 0;

    for (; i < songTitle.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        songResultBox.Items.Clear();
        var songResult = from song in SongList
        where song.SongTitle != null && song.SongTitle.Length >= songTitle.Text.Length
            && songTitle.Text == song.SongTitle.Substring(0, i+1)
        select new { sId = song.SongID, album = song.SongAlbum, artist = song.SongArtist, title = song.SongTitle, 
            genre = song.SongGenre, length = song.SongLength };

        foreach (var item in songResult)
        {
            songResultBox.Items.Add(new Song(item.sId, item.album, item.artist, item.title, item.genre, item.length));
                songResultBox.DisplayMember = "FullName";
                songResultBox.ValueMember = "songID";
        }
    }
}
```

Question is: How would I create a button (or 4 in fact) that took the contents of the ListBox 'songResultBox' and sorted its contents by title, album, artist, genre etc.

Comment: I think you should actually sort the data source of the listbox and bind the listbox again. in this way you only deal with your original data structures and not with the ListBox control itself

Comment: the data source of the listbox will be added dynamically at run time. the SongList.Add I have there is just for testing purposes.

Comment: the most simple way will be to implement a `Compare` function and use `List.Sort()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the button, label it depending on what property you want to sort on, add a click event to the button, sort the items (hopefully you've maintained a list of them), then repopulate the listbox:

```
private bool descendingSongTitleSort = false;
private bool descendingArtistSort = false;

// Artist button clicked event
private void artistButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Func<Song, IComparable> sortProp = (song => song.Artist);
    sortListBox(songResultBox, descendingArtistSort, sortProp);
    descendingSongTitleSort = false;
    descendingArtistSort = !descendingArtistSort;
}

// Title button clicked event
private void titleButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Func<Song, IComparable> sortProp = (song => song.Title);
    sortListBox(songResultBox, descendingSongTitleSort, sortProp);
    descendingSongTitleSort = !descendingSongTitleSort;
    descendingArtistSort = false;
}

// Sorting function
private void sortListBox(
    ListBox box, 
    bool descending, 
    Func<Song, IComparable> sortProperty)
{
    List<Song> items = new List<Song>();
    foreach (Object o in box.Items)
    {
        Song s = o as Song;
        items.Add(s);
    }
    box.Items.Clear();
    if(descending)
    {
        items = items.OrderByDescending(sortProperty).ToList(); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        items = items.OrderBy(sortProperty).ToList();
    }
    foreach(Song s in items)
    {
        box.Items.Add(s); 
    }
}
```

The descending bools aren't necessary if you don't want to worry about resorting in the opposite direction.

Comment: @mansonitefirefox I moved the sort function outside the button click event so that you aren't repeating code, and changed it so that it only sorts the items that are in the actual list box.